# what is the correct way to reference variables when using tidyverse with other functions?

Tags: r, tidyverse, reporttools

say I would like to use [reporttools](/questions/tagged/reporttools) with [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse),

I first make sure the packages are loaded,

```
#install.packages("tidyverse", "reporttools")  #Use this to install it, do this only once
library(reporttools); library(tidyverse)
```

Second I test it with a basic  [reporttools](/questions/tagged/reporttools) `tableNominal`, i.e.,

```
data(CO2)
## the basic function
reporttools::tableNominal(vars = CO2[, 1:2], group = CO2[, "Treatment"])
```

That works.

Now, what is the correct way/best way to reference variables if I wish to use  [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) to subset and select before using [reporttools](/questions/tagged/reporttools)? Would be neat if I could use [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse)'s *select helpers*, e.g. `contains()`, `one_of()`

```
CO2 %>% select(Plant, Type, Treatment) %>% 
     reporttools::tableNominal(vars = vars(Plant, Type), group =  vars(Treatment))
```

Comment: `%>% { reporttools::tableNominal(vars = .[c("Plant", "Type")], group =  .["Treatment"]) }` ?

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to code it in a way that allowed me to use [tidyverse's _select helpers_, e.g `starts_with()`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select_helpers.html)?

Comment: You'll have to rewrite the `tableNominal` function, or write a wrapper around it.